# Custom range css and full names in month selector: Antd datepicker

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I am using antd `DatePicker` for date range purposes.

How can I style the selected range css to have custom css for the start and end of the range, and for the in between selected dates?

Also when I click on the month, I need the full months name with year like `January 2020`, `February 2020` on top - rather that the year.

Also in the month section it shows `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar` as months abbreviation. Likewise I need that to be full month names like `January`, `February`, etc.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.css

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { DatePicker } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import moment from "moment";

const { RangePicker } = DatePicker;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <br />
      <RangePicker />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Current Range Styling]
[image: Current Range Picker Behavior]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can style the start, selected range, and end quite easily using the following classes.

e.g.

```css
/* before */
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-start .ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background: green;
}


/* after */
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-range-end .ant-picker-cell-inner {
  background: purple;
}


/* range */
.ant-picker-cell-in-view.ant-picker-cell-in-range::before {
  background: red;
}
```

Gives the following...

[image: custom styling of calendar]

Unfortunately for the other bits around customising the RangePicker header, I don't believe it exposes any methods to accomplish what you want.

See the official documentation: https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker

Comment: Thanks. I see antd internally uses two input fields for start and end. Can it be customized so that there can be just one input for range

Comment: @li97 No - `RangePicker` is for selecting a start and end date, so has two inputs. The other single inputs aside from the basic DatePicker are `DatePicker[picker="month"]`, `DatePicker[picker="week"]`, `DatePicker[picker="year"]`, and `DatePicker[picker="quarter"]`  see https://ant.design/components/date-picker/  - you might be better served using something like: https://hypeserver.github.io/react-date-range/#daterangepicker

Comment: How do I remove the gap between first element and the range? Same goes with the last element as well. Also when drag my mouse over to select the ranges, I dont want those dotted lines coming, just want the purple color to be coming during selection. can you help?

Comment: Also when I hover on the selected range, the color is back to blue with your approach. it should be purple right? https://codesandbox.io/s/black-breeze-6gmz85?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: The gaps would just be the pseudo selectors `::after`, likewise with `::hover` for mouse over...I have no idea how you want it to look for you in every context. I think you would need to ask another question with specifics - the comments section isn't really for further questions. See my edit

Answer (score -1):

For month picker you can add this as a prop (it will show full months name on month picker):

```
<RangePicker monthCellRender={(date) => date.format("MMMM")} />
```

For year cell there isn't that prop yet, but maybe it will be added in future.

As alternative you could use panelRender prop for custom panel render but that is overkill for your case if you ask me.

Comment: monthCellRender is for the cells in the calendar, not the clickable elements in the header.